# Multiple Java Scriptlet on the same JSP Page

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

I want to select the SQL data with WHERE clause, but I have no idea how to work with it.

My expected SQL query: `SELECT * FROM OLSUSER WHERE user=login_user;`

This is my HttpSession with Java Sciptlet tag

```
<%
    HttpSession sessions = request.getSession(false);
    String login_user = (String) sessions.getAttribute("l_user");
    String login_role = (String) sessions.getAttribute("l_role");
%>
```

This is SQL Selection with Sciptlet tag

```
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample", "app", "app");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from OLSOrder");
%><table border=1 align=center style="text-align: center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   //table data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)* to passed value in your `select` query.For example :-

```
<%
    HttpSession sessions = request.getSession(false);
    String login_user = (String) sessions.getAttribute("l_user");
    String login_role = (String) sessions.getAttribute("l_role");
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample", "app", "app");
        //passing your query in preparestatement using (?)   
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from OLSUSER  where user=?");
           //putting value for placeholder (?)
              ps.setString(1,login_user);
             ResultSet resultset= ps.executeQuery();
     %>
 <!--printing table-->
    <table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
             <tr bgcolor="#d9ac26">
                  <th>Columnname</th>
                  <th>Columnname </th>
                  <!--print same as above--> 
              </tr>
                <% while(resultset.next()){ %>       
             <tr>
                 <td><%=resultset.getString("yourcolumnname")%> </td>
                 <td><%=resultset.getString("yourcolumnname")%> </td>
               <!--print same as above-->
              </tr>
              <% } %>
          </table>
```